# authentication using yammer

Tags: rest, yammer, office365-restapi

i am integrating my CRM application to `Yammer` for that i have create an App inside `Yammer` and by using ClientID, Client Secret and redirect URL i am authenticating an Yammer user to app.

Problem is, that whenever user changes password or any other user trying to login through app it asks to allow permission or not. I just dont want this if any user logging in to yammer by using my app it should automatically allow. please help me regarding this i am posting my code also

```
referalUrl = oauthUrl + clientId;
            oauthUrl =oauthUrl+ clientId + "&redirect_uri=" + redirUrl;      //For authentication to Yammer
            //referalUrl = oauthUrl + clientId;
            accessTokenUrl = accessTokenUrl + "client_id=" + clientId + "&client_secret=" + clientSecret + "&code=";
            string qsCode = string.Empty;
            string accessToken = "";
            string postResults = string.Empty;
            string response = string.Empty;
            string firstName = string.Empty;
            string lastName = string.Empty;
            //string currentUser = string.Empty;
            object yammerUserId = this.PrimaryDataRow[YammerUserTable.Field.YammerUserId];
            object currentUserId = this.SystemClient.UserProfile.EmployeeId;


        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
        {
            while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(qsCode))
            {
                response = YammerAPIRequest.MakeGetRequest(oauthUrl, null, true);

                //look for authenticity token
                string authToken = YammerAPIRequest.GetAuthenticityToken(response);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authToken))
                {
                    string f = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(authToken);

                    userName = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(userName);
                    //password = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(password);
                    string postBody = "utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(authToken) + "&network_permalink=aptean.com&login=" +
                        userName + "&password=" + password + "&remember_me=on";

                    postResults = YammerAPIRequest.MakeLoginPostRequest(postBody, loginUrl, f, null, referalUrl);
                }
                qsCode = postResults;
                if (qsCode.IndexOf("code") == -1 && qsCode.IndexOf("redirect_uri")==-1)
                {
                    PivotalMessageBox.Show("Please enter Correct Username or Password");
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    PivotalMessageBox.Show("You have Logged in to Yammer");
                    string postreq = "utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(authToken) + "&allow=Allow";
                    string allowurl="https://www.yammer.com/aptean.com/oauth2/decision?client_id=BAUC8GdiEZ5ximkabWM9Q&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.yammer.com%2Faptean.com%2F&response_type=code";
                    string allow = YammerAPIRequest.AllowtoApp(postreq, allowurl, authToken, null, null);
                    if (allow != "")
                    {
                        qsCode = allow;
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I just dont want this if any user logging in to yammer by using my app
>   it should automatically allow

This is by design and can't be altered/bypassed from your code. Users must be given the option to Allow or Deny the use of yammer third party applications.

You may consider using the impersonation endpoint if it suits your use case - https://developer.yammer.com/docs/impersonation